# get highest number of order on a single date

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

My model is like

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeginKey(User)
    completion_date_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to get date on which max number of order placed with count of order

Comment: could you please add more detail ?!!

Comment: @mujad   I want  to highest number of  Orders  list  which are completed on a single date.  Like If there are max number of orders completed on 1/1/2020 It will tell that this date I completed max order with list of orders